# Как это убрать?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Такая проблема, когда я работаю с XML файлом каждый раз при создании нового вью элемента я получаю вот такое окно... Как его убрать? Раньше такого не было, а сейчас каждый раз мне нужно тянуться за крестиком в угол экрана...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это у вас доеументация вылезает. Попробуйте её через Ctrl+Q закрыть

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Editor</kbd>→<kbd>General</kbd>→<kbd>Code Completion</kbd>→*Autopopup documentation in (ms)* галочку уберите